# What are the usability limitations of Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Some I know are:

- No HW wallet support
- No SPV mode
- Hard to use as an offline wallet

Are there any others?

Comment: For the first one, it's implemented externally: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/HWI . For the second one, i think some contributors plan to implement a BIP158 version (needs confirmation). For the third one: it's a bit contradictory for a P2P client to be offline ?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any others?

- No support from mnemonic recovery phrases, also known as seed phrases or backup phrases.

Comment: although it will be supported in the next release (0.21) which is expected in late Jan/early Feb 2021 (a few weeks from now)